# Yii CGridVIew filter dropdown with relations

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii 1.1.16 and in my CGridView, i'm adding a custom filter dropdown. But in the dropdown the value is set, but not the text. any idea why?

here is the html

```
<select name="Comments[make]">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="02"></option>
<option value="33"></option>
<option value="31"></option>
</select>
```

in my CGridView i have this

```
array(
            'name'=>'make',
            'filter'=>array_map("strtoupper", CHtml::listData(Posts::model()->with('abc')->findAll(array('group'=> 'abc.make')), 'id', 'abc.make')),
            'value'=>'strtoupper($data->_abc->make)',
        ),
```

and in my `Posts.php` model i have this

```
/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
        'abc' => array(self::HAS_MANY, "Abc", array("make_code" => "make_code", "model_code"=>"model_code")),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 'filter'=>array_map( CHtml::listData(Posts::model()->with('abc')->
  findAll(array('group'=> 'abc.make')), 'id', 'abc.make')),
```

Comment: im getting a syntax error. Is this right? `array('condition'=> 'group' ="abc.make"')`

Comment: now i get this `Posts and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "where".`

Answer (score 0):

Try This;-

In ListData

```
 CHtml::listData(Posts::model()->with('abc')->
     findAll(array('condition'=>'group="abc.make"')),
  'id', 'abc.make')
```

Comment: adding `array('condition'=>'group="abc.make"')array('group'=> 'abc.make')` doesn't work either